# make ajax wait until each with get is finished

Tags: ajax, get, each, activity-finish

I have a jquery .each loop with a .get inside. I want to wait until all gets inside the loop are completed (each get pushes at .complete a new element into an array) and then make an ajax post request to a php file to save the created array. I don't know how I can make the ajax request wait until the each is finished. Until now the ajax fires very quickly and therefore the array is still empty as the gets inside the each are still not finished when it fires. Maybe you have an idea.

Here is the script:

```
$('#ScanButton, .ScanButton').click(function() {

var array = ["http://www.xyz.com/bla/bla/summary.html",
             "http://www.xyz.com/blu/blu/summary.html",
            ];

dataArray = [];

$.each(array, function(n, val) { 


    $.get(val, function(res) { //get the html source of this website



      var data = {

      }

  }).complete(function() { 
        alert("complete"); 
        dataArray.push(data);
    });

});

    data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(dataArray);      

  $.ajax({
    async:           false,
    type:           'post',
    cache:          false,
    url:            'test.php',
    data:           {myJson:  data}
    });

  return false;
```

});

I appreciate any help. Thank you :)

Comment: Will the "same origin policy" be an issue as the .get() function is a shorthand function of .ajax(), which is affected by this. More info on this can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy? Hope that helps.

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of same origin policy. Thank you!:) I got a workaround that works (it's just for a private project). But until now after each loop the ajax post request is fired. I want to minimize these requests to one. This is why the last ajax post request should be fired after the loops are finished and the array is complete to be passed on.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.js has an [elegant solution to this sort of problem](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#after).

```
var renderNotes = _.after(notes.length, render);
_.each(notes, function(note) {
  note.asyncSave({success: renderNotes}); 
});
// renderNotes is run once, after all notes have saved.
```